# Perform several operations with an assembler and C interface

Tags: c, assembly, intel, fpu

I am trying to perform different operations with assembler for FPU unit of the Intel processors, inside an interface with C.
The operations to be performed are:

```
43.001 * 0.00751
0.00000001 * 1.4142135623730951
0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 − 0.3
```

This is the C code with the assembler interface:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
double r;
double s;
const double a = 1;
const double b = 0.1;
const double c = 43.001; 
const double d = 0.00751;
const double e = 0.00000001; 
const double f = 1.4142135623730951;    
const double g = 0.3;   

__asm__ ("fldl %1;" //cargo a
        "fldl %2;"  //cargo b
        "fldl %3;"  //cargo c
        "fldl %4;"  //cargo d
        "faddp;"   // suma a con b y lo guarda en st(0)
        "fmul st2,st3" // c*d y lo guarda en st(2)
        "fstl %0;" : "=m" (r) : "m" (a), "m" (b)
        "fstl %1;" : "=m" (s) : "m" (c), "m" (d)    //acá creí que se se podia hacer la multiplicación
        );

printf("%.16e\n", r);
printf("%.16e\n", s);   
return 0;
}
```

The idea is that the result of each operation is stored in a stack position, but I have not been able to do it because I'm not sure if the syntax of for example fmul st2, st3 is correct. How do you store each operation in a stack position and then print the results?

Comment: There is no such instruction `fmul st2,st3`.  One of the operands of `fmul` has to be `st0`.  Likewise, the syntax of your `__asm__` statement seems wrong.  Learning  assembly through inline assembly is a really bad idea.  Why not program in assembly entirely instead of doing it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I found it.

I wrote this code that perform the operations in independent blocks of asm.

```html
int main(void)
{
double result_mult1;
double result_mult2;
double result_resta;
const double a = 43.001;
const double b = 0.00751;
const double c = 0.00000001; 
const double d = 1.4142135623730951;
const double e = 0.1;
const double f = e+e+e; 
const double g = 0.3;

__asm__ ("fldl %1;" //Carga a
   "fldl %2;" //Carga b
   "fmulp;"
   "fstl %0;" : "=m" (result_mult1) : "m" (a), "m" (b) );
   
__asm__ ("fldl %1;" //Carga c
   "fldl %2;" //Carga d
   "fmulp;"
   "fstl %0;" : "=m" (result_mult2) : "m" (c), "m" (d) );
   
__asm__("fldl %1;" //Carga g
  "fldl %2;" //Carga f
  "fsubp;"   //Resta g con f y lo guarda en st(0)
  "fstl %0;" : "=m" (result_resta) : "m" (g), "m" (f)); 

printf("%.16e\n", result_mult1);
printf("%.16e\n", result_mult2);
printf("%.16e\n", result_resta);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're still leaving stuff building up on the x87 stack because you're not using `fstp`.  If you did this repeatedly, you'd get NaNs from overflowing the x87 stack.  Each of your blocks leaves one more x87 stack register used from 2 loads + one pop.